# How to re-enable the default binding in an override

Tags: java, guice

I have a `TestModule` which does several bindings for my unit tests, e.g. it replaces accessor classes for external systems with stubs:

```
bind(ExternalSystemAccessor.class).to(ExternalSystemAccessorStub.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Now one of my tests needs to use the productive implementation, so I tried to bind it back the default with an override:

```
injector = Guice.createInjector(Modules.override(new TestModule()).with(new AbstractModule() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ExternalSystemAccessor.class).to(ExternalSystemAccessor.class);
    }
}));
```

However, this leads to a Guice error:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Binding points to itself.
```

So how can I get back to the default binding with an override?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but as a general rule of thumb it's better to avoid `Modules.override` whenever possible. Instead, you should refactor your modules so that you can write tests by simply not installing production bindings, rather than by installing and then overriding them. I often will have a public module that simply installs a bunch of package-private modules, which allows me to install different subsets of the modules for tests.

Comment: I'm not overriding a production binding but a test binding.

Comment: All the more reason to not use `Modules.override` then. Simply factor your test module to not install that binding if you want to supply it yourself.

Comment: There is one test out of twenty that needs a different binding. Do whatever you want, but *I* won't create any additional module just for that one test, but I'll use `Modules.override`

Comment: You are of course free to write whatever code you want. That said, the reason to avoid `Modules.override` -- along with other Guice features that change the injector structure, like private modules -- in tests is so that your test injector more closely mirrors a real injector. `Modules.override` is very analogous to mocking tools like `Mockito.spy` which wrap a real object and pass through some of the method calls. Once in a while that's the right approach, but it's also a good way for small changes in your test or tested code to cause failures that are really difficult to debug.

Comment: Oh, and you make it sound like creating a new module for a test is a large burden. I'm not sure I agree -- it's easy enough to create a new module class inline inside your test, and in fact that's a really flexible way to ensure that each test gets exactly the right bindings. I like using [BoundFieldModule](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BoundFields) for this, which I think is the easiest way to create a new module just for a single test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer while typing the question. The solution is to omit the `to` method:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(ExternalSystemAccessor.class); // re-enable default binding
}
```